# Fix jQuery block element animation

Tags: jquery, css, layout

I have a navigation I'm working on where one sublinks has a large quantity of sublinks. I'd like the sublinks box to open below the navigation in a nice slideDown box. I have it working in two instances (where the subnav just appears and you can select items and where the subnav slides out, but you can't select items) but I can't seem to get it to do what I want at the same time.

Unfortunately I have all the code on my laptop and I'm without a network here, so I can't post the code at the moment. An example of what I want it to do is on http://www.irfu.ie/home.php

My HTML is the following:

```
<li><a href="" class="nav">TopLink</a>
<div class="navLinks">
    <ul>
        <li><a href... </li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
</li>
```

My jQuery is as follows:

```
$(function(){
    $('nav').hover(
        function(){
            $('navLinks').slideDown();
        },

        function(){
            $('navLinks').slideUp();
        }
    );
});
```

And my stylesheet is as follows:

```
div.navLinks {z-index:5;position:absolute;width:920px;display:none;}
```

I can add the following to the stylesheet:

```
div.navLinks li:hover div {display:block}
```

And it will just appear (no sliding animation) and I can rollover the links. Without that, the box will slide down, but I can't roll over any of the links (when I move off the navigation link to try and enter the box, it disappears).

Been driving me, just a bit spare so any help would be greatly appreciated!

T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bloody typical!!! As I was reviewing the question, I realised that the class "nav" is on the anchor, not on the list item!!! Moved the class to the li as follows:

```
<li class="nav"><a href="">TopLink</a>
```

Instead of:

```
<li><a href="" class="nav">TopLink</a>
```

And it all works swimmingly!!!

So simple... hate those ones. Love solving my own issues though!

T